# WordPress Creating Front end posting plugin

Tags: wordpress, frontend, posting

I try to create a plugin allow users to add new post, edit post, and delete post  from the front end.
Now when the user try to edit the post instead of updating the the same post the plugin create new **page** ! in pending status.
Can anyone help me please?
This is the code of edit post class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Edit Post form class
 *
 * @author Engr.MTH
 * @package MOSTASHAROON Frontend Form
 */
class MOSFF_Edit_Post {

    function __construct() {
        add_shortcode( 'mosff_editpost', array($this, 'shortcode') );
    }

    /**
     * Handles the edit post shortcode
     *
     * 
     */
    function shortcode() {


$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' =>'-1', 'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'private', 'trash') ) );

if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();global $post;

    if(isset($_GET['post'])) {

        if($_GET['post'] == $post->ID)
        {
            $current_post = $post->ID;

            $title = get_the_title();
            $content = get_the_content();

            $custom_one = get_post_meta($current_post, 'vsip_custom_one', true);
            $custom_two = get_post_meta($current_post, 'vsip_custom_two', true);
        }
    }

endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();

global $current_post;

$postTitleError = '';

if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['post_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce')) {

    if(trim($_POST['postTitle']) === '') {
        $postTitleError = 'Please enter a title.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $postTitle = trim($_POST['postTitle']);
    }

    $post_information = array(
        'ID' => $current_post,
        'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postTitle'])),
        'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postContent'])),
        'post-type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'pending'
    );

    $post_id = wp_update_post($post_information);

    if($post_id)
    {

        // Update Custom Meta
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'vsip_custom_one', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['customMetaOne'])));
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'vsip_custom_two', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['customMetaTwo'])));

        wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;
    }

}

?>



    <!-- #primary BEGIN -->
    <div id="primary">

        <form action="" id="primaryPostForm" method="POST">

            <fieldset>

                <label for="postTitle"><?php _e('Post\'s Title:', 'framework') ?></label>

                <input type="text" name="postTitle" id="postTitle" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" class="required" />

            </fieldset>

            <?php if($postTitleError != '') { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $postTitleError; ?></span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <?php } ?>

            <fieldset>

                <label for="postContent"><?php _e('Post\'s Content:', 'framework') ?></label>

                <textarea name="postContent" id="postContent" rows="8" cols="30"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>

            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>

                <label for="customMetaOne"><?php _e('Custom Meta One:', 'framework') ?></label>

                <input type="text" name="customMetaOne" id="customMetaOne" value="<?php echo $custom_one; ?>" />

            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>

                <label for="customMetaTwo"><?php _e('Custom Meta Two:', 'framework') ?></label>

                <input type="text" name="customMetaTwo" id="customMetaTwo" value="<?php echo $custom_two; ?>" />

            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>

                <?php wp_nonce_field('post_nonce', 'post_nonce_field'); ?>

                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                <button type="submit"><?php _e('Update Post', 'framework') ?></button>

            </fieldset>

        </form>


    </div><!-- #primary END -->

<?php }}
$mosff_editpostform = new MOSFF_Edit_Post();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, just I remove this line:

```
global $current_post;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by getting the post id and query it to get all the fields of the particular and edit it through a form  and post it again.

get more detailed article here[kvcodes](http://kvcodes.com/2014/06/wordpress-edit-posts-front-end/).

Comment: the link might give an answer to the question, but please also include essential part of the solution *clearly* in the answer post..